# Android: ForegroundColorSpan not working on some devices

Tags: android

I have the following code that sets a color to a portion of the text:

```
String fontString = "  \u25FC";
Spannable iconSpannable = new SpannableString(fontString);
int color = Color.parseColor("#ff00ff00");
iconSpannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(color), 0, fontString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();
builder.append(iconSpannable);

TextView labelView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label);
labelView.setText(builder, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Here's the result in a Moto X (shows color as intended):

[image: Moto X - works OK]

and with a Samsung J1 (doesn't show color):

[image]

Any ideas on what could be the cause of this difference?

Edit: the color does work with ASCII characters, so the non-ascii character must be the culprit.

Comment: what happens if you replace `"  \u25FC"` with `"  \u25FC TEST  \u25FC"` ? (ascii + non ascii in one `ForegroundColorSpan`)

Comment: @pskink in that case only `TEST` is colored.